# Termux change repo removed

Tags: repo, termux

I tried changing the repository even after using
pkg remove game repo. Has the command been changed?

```
>$termux-change-repo
 termux-change-repo: command not found
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? Like Termux version, ...?

Comment: I rechecked, it seems I was using a much older version 0.101.

Comment: @raspiduino but still, does the command just become non existent because of the version?

Comment: If you got version 0.101, I guess you are using the [Google Play version](https://github.com/termux/termux-app#google-play-store-deprecated). Is that correct?

Comment: yh it's from play store

Comment: As you can see from the link above, it is **deprecated**. In the past I also installed that one (when I knew nothing) and neither apt repos nor commands in the wiki worked

Answer (score 2):

**Uninstall** the old version `version 0.101`

Then install the latest one `version 0.118`

You can find it on apk sites or fdroid or github

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As @Dameslayer say, you have to upgrade the version. It is currently working in the `version 0.118`. But it is not downloadable from the app store.

1. First, uninstall all the termux apps that you have in the device.
2. Go to [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/) site and download the termux apk. (F-Droid is an
   installable catalogue of FOSS (Free and Open Source Software)).
3. Open the app and everything sould be working fine.